# Reasign to undefined argument cause global definition?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
Line.prototype.b = function (a) {
    a = a || this.a();
    return this.y - a * this.x;
}
```

I was wondering if `a = a || a();` cause `a` become a global definition variable in case parameter `a` is undefined, like if I call that function without parameter.

Comment: `a = a || a();` - This will throw. If `a` is falsy, it obviously isn't a function and hence cannot be invoked. I think you want `a && a()`

Comment: No.  But what in the world could that mean, though?  You're saying, "if `a` is not truthy (which all functions are), then set `a` to the value found by calling `a`".  Something's awry.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: oops, `its this.a();`. Sorry ^^

Comment: @ScottSauyet updated. Sorry. ^^

Comment: Ahh, that makes much more sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `a` will remain a parameter of the function because it is a declared argument.